# Apache2 não executa arquivos php

Tags: php, apache

Meus arquivos php não são executados no browser quando acesso o localhost (var/www/html/index.php). O código é exibido como se fosse um arquivo de texto comum.

Configs do sistema:
Apache2
Ubuntu 18.04 LRS
Php 7.2.0

Algum problema na instalação (apache2 ou php) ou configuração?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui solucionar.
Se alguém teve o mesmo problema, primeiro eu desinstalei o php:

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
```

depois instalei novamente

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

e habilitei para o apache 2

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0

sudo systemctl restar apache2
```

Comment: faltou o t em restart não consegui editar porque é um erro pequeno,
Também usei 7.4 ao invés de 7.0